# Chrome times out on streaming FFMPEG output from ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, azure, ffmpeg

I've got a unique problem here!

**UPDATE 2** So it turns out the development below is FALSE, the inconsistency of the bug made it seem like not closing the stream made it work... but in fact the same issue persists!

<s>**UPDATE** Interesting development; if I comment out `ffmpegBufferedIn.Close();` below, the entire stream always goes through fine... the request just never ends. What could be going on here?</s>

I'm writing a web service that stores audio files in Azure Blob Storage, and converts them to MP3 live when requested through my ASP.NET Web API endpoint. I accomplish this by using 'DownloadToStream' via the Azure Storage API, feeding that stream through the STDIN of an FFMPEG process, and sending the STDOUT stream as the request response.

**The block of code that does this looks like this:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid songid)
{
    // This could take awhile.
    HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 600;

    Process ffmpeg = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/executables/ffmpeg.exe"), "-i - -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 - ");
    startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    ffmpeg.StartInfo = startinfo;
    ffmpeg.ErrorDataReceived += ffmpeg_ErrorDataReceived;

    // Our response is a stream
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("songs");

    // Retrieve reference to a blob
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(songid.ToString());

    ffmpeg.Start();
    ffmpeg.BeginErrorReadLine();

    // Buffer the streams
    var ffmpegBufferedIn = new BufferedStream(ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream);
    var ffmpegBufferedOut = new BufferedStream(ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream);

    blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ffmpegBufferedIn).ContinueWith((t) => {
        ffmpegBufferedIn.Flush();
        ffmpegBufferedIn.Close();
    });

    response.Content = new StreamContent(ffmpegBufferedOut);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/mpeg");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Returned response.");
    return response;
}
```

This works quite well in all browsers - all except for Chrome, which has an interesting way of buffering audio streams. Chrome will buffer the first ~2 megabytes of a stream, then keep the connection open and wait until the user gets closer to playing the next segment of a file before consuming the rest of the stream. This should be fine - and for some songs it is. For others, I get this:

[image: Chrome error]

At first I thought this was due to some kind of timeout - But it happens at a different time and size for each file. It is consistent within about 15 seconds on the same songs, however. The output on the server side is normal - no exceptions thrown, and FFMpeg finishes encoding the song successfully.

**Here's the server-side output of the above request:**

```
ffmpeg version N-64919-ga613257 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 23 2014 00:27:32 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 92.101 / 52. 92.101
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.101 / 55. 48.101
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.102 /  4. 11.102
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    TSRC            : AUUM71001516
    title           : Sunlight
    track           : 2
    artist          : Bag Raiders
    copyright       : 2010 Modular Recordings
    genre           : Electronic
    album           : Bag Raiders
    album_artist    : Bag Raiders
    disc            : 1/1
    publisher       : Modular Recordings
    composer        : Chris Stracey/Jack Glass/Dan Black
    date            : 2010
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg), 600x600 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : 
      comment         : Other
Output #0, mp3, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    TSRC            : AUUM71001516
    TIT2            : Sunlight
    TRCK            : 2
    TPE1            : Bag Raiders
    TCOP            : 2010 Modular Recordings
    TCON            : Electronic
    TALB            : Bag Raiders
    TPE2            : Bag Raiders
    TPOS            : 1/1
    TPUB            : Modular Recordings
    TCOM            : Chris Stracey/Jack Glass/Dan Black
    TDRL            : 2010
    TSSE            : Lavf55.48.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.69.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
size=       6kB time=00:00:00.21 bitrate= 227.6kbits/s    
size=     102kB time=00:00:04.31 bitrate= 193.7kbits/s    
size=     202kB time=00:00:08.56 bitrate= 192.9kbits/s    
size=     341kB time=00:00:14.49 bitrate= 192.5kbits/s    
size=     489kB time=00:00:20.82 bitrate= 192.4kbits/s    
size=     642kB time=00:00:27.35 bitrate= 192.3kbits/s    
size=     792kB time=00:00:33.75 bitrate= 192.2kbits/s    
size=     950kB time=00:00:40.49 bitrate= 192.2kbits/s    
size=    1106kB time=00:00:47.15 bitrate= 192.2kbits/s    
size=    1258kB time=00:00:53.63 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    1415kB time=00:01:00.31 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    1563kB time=00:01:06.66 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    1710kB time=00:01:12.90 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    1857kB time=00:01:19.17 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    2008kB time=00:01:25.63 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    2162kB time=00:01:32.21 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    2299kB time=00:01:38.03 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    2457kB time=00:01:44.80 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    2600kB time=00:01:50.89 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    2755kB time=00:01:57.52 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    2864kB time=00:02:02.17 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    3022kB time=00:02:08.88 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    3172kB time=00:02:15.31 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    3284kB time=00:02:20.06 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    3385kB time=00:02:24.40 bitrate= 192.1kbits/s    
size=    3529kB time=00:02:30.51 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    3687kB time=00:02:37.25 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    3838kB time=00:02:43.71 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    3988kB time=00:02:50.11 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    4138kB time=00:02:56.53 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    4279kB time=00:03:02.54 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    4408kB time=00:03:08.03 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    4544kB time=00:03:13.85 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    4683kB time=00:03:19.78 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    4805kB time=00:03:24.95 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    4939kB time=00:03:30.67 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    5049kB time=00:03:35.38 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    5141kB time=00:03:39.32 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    5263kB time=00:03:44.49 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    5372kB time=00:03:49.17 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
The thread 0xb24 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
size=    5436kB time=00:03:51.91 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    5509kB time=00:03:55.02 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    5657kB time=00:04:01.32 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
size=    5702kB time=00:04:03.22 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s

video:0kB audio:5701kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.005738%
```

Any ideas? I'm grateful for suggestions - I've been chasing this for a week now!

Comment: for what sake you are streaming meadia theough a web role and not using Azure Media Services??

Comment: Azure Media Services does not support the range of audio codecs I need.

Comment: are you sure? Azure Media Services official documentation does not show you how to do H.264 baseline profile encoding, but apparently you can: http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/04/bending-windows-azure-media.html The official documentation will also not show you how to trim/cut video, but you can do that too: http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/04/bending-azure-media-services-clip-or.html From what I see in your ffmpeg output, There is nothing extraordinary in your Audio to not being supported by Media Services. Just need to find it out :)

Comment: I haven't found anything claiming support for audio codecs like FLAC and OGG, which unfortunately are absolutely necessary for me! If they were supported I would definitely use Azure Media Services.

Comment: Hi Hayden, I'm facing the same issue. Where you able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the difference from the speed you convert the audio and the speed you consume it.

You are filling one buffer to `ffmpegBufferedIn` and sending it to `ffmpeg` but you are only reading from the `ffmpegBufferedOut` when the user browser reads it, what is happening is when the process finishes and the user is not finished consuming the `ffmpegBufferedOut` you have a race between the garbage collector and the user consuming the `ffmpegBufferedOut`.

If you never close the `ffmpegBufferedIn` it will never garbage collect it because the process is waiting for more data from the stream, so it works.

Solution you need to detect when the response is finished sending and only than close the stream resources, I'm not really sure how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I figured it might be something like that. I'll pursue this a bit further and if it leads me to the answer or I don't receive any others, I'll mark this resolved.

Comment: I've updated the question - leaving the stream open doesn't actually resolve the issue. I don't think GC is the problem here -- I kept references around for every required object, and the connection still failed.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the **ffmpegBufferedIn** stream after the **DownloadToStreamAsync** task complete may help. See [Task.ContinueWith(TResult) Method (Func(Task, TResult)) (System.Threading.Tasks)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ffmpegBufferedIn).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    ffmpegBufferedIn.Flush();
    //ffmpegBufferedIn.Close();
}).Wait();
ffmpegBufferedIn.Close();
```

Comment: Check out my update above - it turns out that not closing the stream actually doesn't make any difference! Thanks for the answer, though.